# Extract UDP packet payload from a ethernet frame

Tags: c, linux, networking, udp, tcp

I am writing UDP send/recv using some Layer-2 API. 
I can receive the Ethernet frame containing my UDP packet. For example, I send **"hello"** and got the following Ethernet frame.

```
000f 5325 fb00 000f 5324 8c30 0800 4500   
0022 0000 4000 4011 5b0c 0a80 657d 0a80 
6542 c179 15b3 000e 46a2 3068 656c 6c6f 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

where

```
000f 5325 fb00 : destination MAC
000f 5324 8c30 : source MAC
0800           : Ethernet type
....
68 656c 6c6f   : "hello"
```

If I use different programs to send UDP packets, the starting bit of my message/payload ("hello") varies.

**Question:** How can I extract the payload?

I need to keep my UDP protocol implementation as lean as possible, so I better write them in C. But library or system functions related is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use POSIX Socket API in Linux. You can create UDP sockets and recvfrom() call can get you your UDP payload.

Comment: I am building my own UDP protocol. So BSD socket programming is not an option here. that's why I have to handle these ethernet frames on my own:-(